# Android: Thread seems to run too long, meaning even after it has been stopped

Tags: java, android, multithreading, surfaceview

I have a thread in Android painting on a canvas. It all works fine, but if I press the back button the app crashes because the thread still tries to draw on the canvas which is at that time null already. From the code I would say the thread should never reach that piece of code anymore.

On pressing the back button my Surface gets destroyed:

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
{
    boolean retry = true;
    thread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) 
    {
        try 
        {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see above I set thread.setRunning to false, my thread does this

```
  public void run() 
  {
      while (run) 
      {
          Canvas c = null;
          try 
          {
              c = sh.lockCanvas(null);
              synchronized (sh) 
              {
                  doDraw(c);
              }
          } 
          finally 
          {
              if (c != null) 
              {
                  sh.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
              }
          }
    }
  }
```

The while loop should stop as soon as I have set this var to false, but it still enters the doDraw() method. I don't understand why the doDraw (here I get my null pointer excepetion) is still being called. Any one an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not Android expert, rather beginner, but what about extending synchronized blocks (you have to have reading value and using the value as one atom operation), ex.

```
          synchronized (sh) 
          {
               c = sh.lockCanvas(null);                  
               doDraw(c);
          }
```

Moreover perhaps could you stop/destroy your addintional thread in onStop either onDestroy method of your activity?

I'm wondering also about finally block. Perhaps it should be synchronized too? Not sure...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it could work for you, but you can try to do same task in an **IntentService**.

An IntentService is stopped while the activity finishes, maybe it will solve your problem. I suppose you're using a handler for drawing in the doDraw method, am I wrong? Please, let me know your thoughts and results

Comment: IntentService might work as well, don't know why all tutorials to draw on canvas use thread and not intnetService. Does anyone know a reason?

Comment: Don't know why. I think that maybe probably it is due to the habit of working same way like most people did in Java. Try if it works using an IntentService and if it works let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

`Thread#join` doesn't kill the thread, it just waits for it to die. You should either break the loop inside your thread by setting `run=false` or use methods like `stop` or `interrupt`. They are deprecated and basically should never be used.

Comment: Run is set to false right at the beginning of surfaceDestroyed